# How do I create a new object on every button click?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I am creating a notes app, and I've all but finished it. My app starts on the main activity, which shows a `recylcerView` displaying all of the saved notes. To create a new note, you press a button, which sends you to another activity where you write your note. You then press a button that saves the note as an instance of the `Note` class and sends that object instance back to the main activity where it updates the recyclerView.

My problem is, every time I press the save button for my note, it just updates the Note instance instead of creating an entirely new one. How do I get it to create a new instance of the Note class so that I can have more than one saved note?

Here is my code for the save button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddNoteActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

String mTitle = title.getText().toString();
String mContent = content.getText().toString();

intent.putExtra("notePar", new Note(mTitle, mContent));

startActivity(intent);
```

Here is my code for the mainactivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

Note sentParcNote = intent.getParcelableExtra("notePar");

if(sentParcNote != null) {
   notes.add(sentParcNote);
}
```

Comment: Your current code isn't sufficient for me to determine where the problem might be. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, how are you storing the notes to display in the recycler view? Do you have a list of `Note` objects or a database that stores them or a file or what?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `startActivity(intent)` to navigate from `AddNoteActivity` to `MainActivity`, this method is used to start a new activity, which means, the system will create a new instance of `MainActivity` class and put it at the top of the activity stack. This way you will always have 0 or 1 note (when `sentParcNote != null`)

I would suggest to use `startActivityForResult` when you navigate from `MainActivity` to `AddNoteActivity` and call `setResult` in your `AddNoteActivity`

Example:

`MainActivity`:

Declare this static int at the top of your class (e.g: just before `onCreate` method)

`private static final int ADD_NOTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 2;`

Then add this piece of code on your button action to start `AddNoteActivity`:

```
Intent addNoteIntent = new Intent(this, AddNoteActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(addNoteIntent, ADD_NOTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then to catch the new note from `AddNoteActivity`

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ADD_NOTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Note sentParcNote = data.getParcelableExtra("notePar");

                if(sentParcNote != null) {
                      notes.add(sentParcNote);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`AddNoteActivity`:

add this piece of code to your save button action

```
String mTitle = title.getText().toString();
String mContent = content.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("notePar", new Note(mTitle, mContent));
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
// finish closes the current activity which means in this case it goes back to the MainActivity
finish();
```

I would suggest using local storage to save your notes otherwise if you restart the app you will always have 0 notes.